# How to integrate linkedin with my android project without forcing to install Linkedin App?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

How can I integrate linkedin login and share without using linkedin app. When I follow the documentation which is provided are force me to install the linkedin app to get credentials. Could you please help me to get credentials without forcing to install that app?

Comment: I don't think you can

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedIn Mobile SDK for Android requires the official LinkedIn Android application is also installed to support the SDK's capabilities. But you can use the `REST API` [Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api)